# Retrieve the model and price of the car by using parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, express

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace car_database
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public class car
        {
            string connstring = "Data Source=.\\SqlExpress; Initial Catalog=carsale; Integrated Security=True";

            protected BtnView(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connstring);

                try
                {
                    myConnection.Open();
                    string query = "select model ,price from car where Id =@carid";

                    SqlCommand mycmd = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);

                    int carid1;

                    if (!int.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out carid1))
                    { 
                         Label1.Text = "please enter a numeric ID!";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mycmd.Parameters.Add("@carid", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
                        mycmd.Parameters["@carid"].Value = carid1;

                        SqlDataReader reader = mycmd.ExecuteReader();

                        if (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Label1.Text = "Model:" + reader["model"] + "<br/>" + "price:" + (string)reader["price"];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Label1.Text = "no car has this id ";
                        }

                        reader.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    Label1.Text = ex.Message;
                }
                finally
                {
                    myConnection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to display the car model and price in Label1 when button is clicked according to Id entered in the TextBox1.

aspx markup:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="car_database.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
enter id to retrieve the model and the price of the car :
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" />

            <br />
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn" OnClick ="BtnView" />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But the code does not work - I get some error:

> public class car must have return type

TextBox1.Text and Label1.Text have errors:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field method or property

Comment: `protected BtnView(object sender, EventArgs e)` should be `protected void BtnView(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: Start with the basics: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods. Your code has a couple of issues. A button click method in a class, a class T without a return...

Answer (score 1):

Couple of mistake I see

```
protected BtnView(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
```

Should be

```
protected Void BtnView(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   ....
}
```

Also, `Label1.Text = "please enter a numeric ID!";` should be `this.Label1.Text = "please enter a numeric ID!";` considering `Label1` is the Label control instance name

Comment: The second error still exists:  an object reference is required for the non-static field method or property

Comment: @ReemAbdulaziz that's cause of the `Label1.Text = ""` changed that as suggested in answer for all references

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class **public class car**, the code must be in the **WebForm1** class to have access to its controls.

Try like this:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace car_database
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {



            string connstring = "Data Source=.\\SqlExpress; Initial Catalog=carsale; Integrated Security=True";

            protected BtnView(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connstring);
                try
                {
                    myConnection.Open();
                    string query = "select model ,price from car where Id =@carid";

                    SqlCommand mycmd = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);

                    int carid1;

                    if (!int.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out carid1))
                    { Label1.Text = "please enter a numerac ID!"; }

                    else
                    {
                        mycmd.Parameters.Add("@carid", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
                        mycmd.Parameters["@carid"].Value = carid1;

                        SqlDataReader reader = mycmd.ExecuteReader();

                        if (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Label1.Text = "Model:" + reader["model"] + "<br/>" + "price:" + (string)reader["price"];

                        }

                        else
                        {
                            Label1.Text = "no car has this id ";

                        }

                        reader.Close();
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    Label1.Text = ex.Message;

                }
                finally
                {

                    myConnection.Close();

                }

            }

    }
}
```